# Dynamically add properties to PropertyGroup Class

Tags: python

How can I dynamically add or remove properties in a class like this?
I want to make a user interface where you can click on a button that will add new options and properties in that same user interface but for that I need a way to append new settings into this class.

```
import bpy

class MyPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    custom_1: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="My Float")
    custom_2: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="My Int")


bpy.utils.register_class(MyPropertyGroup)

bpy.types.Object.my_prop_grp = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup)


# test this worked
bpy.data.objects[0].my_prop_grp.custom_1 = 22.0
```

So how would I add a custom_3 property to this class for example?

Comment: Hello, it seems you want to explore [CollectionProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.CollectionProperty)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Do you happen to know how exactly I should use the Collection Property feature? Unfortunately I could not find any examples anywhere. If I replace the PropertyGroup with CollectionProperty I get this error: ""ValueError: register_class(...): expected a subclass of a registerable RNA type (CollectionProperty does not support registration)"". I don't really know what I am doing at this point so any tip would be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Let `MyPropertyGroup` inherit from `bpy.types.PropertyGroup`. Then `bpy.types.Object.my_prop_grp = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type = MyPropertyGroup)` then any object will have a `my_prop_grp` and also have an `add` and `remove` method.